# From C# when calling SSRS report only main report shows data sub report giving error

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I developed an SSRS report having a main and 3 subreport.
I am calling this report from C#.
I only know how to bind the main rdlc with the data set.

I use the code below for this

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\sale_dept.rdl";
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataset.Tables[0]));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

when I run the exe i am getting the report viewer filled with main report but 3 subreport shows error because i didn't specify the DataSource for those subreports

[image]

1. There is no parameter passing between the main and other sub reports
2. The dataset name for the main and all sub report is default as DataSet1

Please guide me to bind the sub reports with appropriate query dataset tables.
I am totally stuck here.

**Edited**

I changed my project with 1 subreport.

In SSRS it is working fine in (the BIDS) editor but when calling from C# it is giving error:

> Could not be found at the specified location. Please verify that the subreport has been published and that the name is correct.

My code:

```
subreportevenhandler according to this question
```

[question for subreport event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331091/how-do-i-fill-a-dataset-in-an-ssrs-subreport)

```
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
    this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\sale_dept.rdl";
     this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
                new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(addsubreport);
     this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataset.Tables[0]));
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();




void addsubreport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();

           SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport", conn);

           SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
           dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);

           e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataset.Tables[0]));
        }
```

Still I am getting error for subreport
I moved all the .rdl file to C# bin folder..

[image]

Main report is showing the data correctly. In SSRS its fine..

Comment: And the sub-report controls (eg Tablix) are bound to the Dataset1s fields? Is it a shared dataset, how do you have it configured?

Comment: @JeremyThompson no each report has its on query and dataset...but the datasetname for all report is Dataset1

Comment: And you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17602237/495455

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes..but in SSRS my report is working fine because no parameter is passing..the query is hard code..the query is build in C# during execution and the datatable filled by dataadapter is given as datasource for the report..Sorry if i am wrong..i naive to this SSRS

Comment: Can you show us with a screenshot how you have wired it up (by editing your question)? Did you get it working with 1 subreport? and can you go back in source control to when it was working and do a diff? The other day I was teaching a Tech-BA in our team how to make reports and we hit a couple of errors! I told him "what you have to do is think really abstractly about the errors as they will only point you in a direction". So in your case create a new report with one subreport working and then compare the settings, also there are a couple of other quick fixes in that link, welcome to SSRS!

Comment: @JeremyThompson i tried with 1 subreport also..both are working fine in SSRS..but in C# sub report is not working..i tried subreporteventhandler also..

Comment: @JeremyThompson pls find my edited question

Comment: @Sachu In your RDL when calling the subreport give the *absolute path* instead of relative path. `SubReport Properties > General > Use this report as subreport`

Comment: @AnupAgrawal in SSRS im doing the same..took the subreport tool then right click `SubReport Properties > General > Use this report as subreport`
and its working perfectly in SSRS with 1 subreport and 3 subreport..pblm is when it call from C#

Comment: Relative path might work in SSRS might not work in C# or other web app. We have encountered similar things before where relative path works in SSRS server but not in web app. My suggestion would be to try absolute path.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal how to give the absolute path..currently what i am doing is right click in subreport then `SubReport Properties > General > Use this report as subreport` then select the report from dropdown.

Comment: @Sachu Yes it doesn't like absolute path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88812/discussion-between-sachu-and-anup-agrawal).

Comment: @AnupAgrawal can you help me to set the path as absolute..i tried but dont got a way to do it

Comment: @Sachu responded to you in chat

Comment: @anupAgrawal issue solved..only thing is just rename the subreport as *.rdlc from *.rdl

Comment: Hi all..thanks for your suggestions and valuable time..its working now..only needed is rename the subreport extension to .rdlc from .rdl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the issue. I am posting it as answer because it may help someone in future.

The `SubreportProcessingEventHandler` will only get fired for `.rdlc` subreports.
In my project main report and all subreports are `.rdl` extension.
So only change I done was went to command prompt and renamed the subreport extension as `.rdlc`

eg:- `ren discount.rdl discount.rdlc`

Then attach the data-set for the sub-report accordingly.

See the code as below

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\main_rpt.rdl";
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(addsubreport);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataset.Tables[0]));
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();


void addsubreport(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{

SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

Switch(e.ReportPath)
{
case "subreport1":
   sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport one", conn);
   dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet for subreport1", dataset.Tables[0]));
   break;
case "subreport2":
   sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport two", conn);
   dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet for subreport2", dataset.Tables[0]));
   break;
case "subreport3":
   sqlcomm = new SqlCommand( "Query for subreport three", conn);
   dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
   e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet for subreport3", dataset.Tables[0]));
   break;

 }

}
```

Switch is needed if you have more than one sub-report. Main point to notice

1. All sub-report should have extension .rdlc

2.if any parameter is passing make sure it is also named correctly.

3. Specify the path correctly. It's better to put main report and subreport in same folder.

Now run the C# application it will show the main report with all sub-report

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid using this to say "Thanks" but seriously, your solution here answered a difficult problem and also put to end a large amount of head-bashing today and yesterday.  The only examples I have been able to find so far on how to deploy sub-reports use parameteter-less SELECT statements, and have no consideration for usability in very busy databases.

Comment: @Dan I'm so glad to see that my answer helped you.