Displaying sub report is giving error as in the pic attached
I have report in which I am trying to display a chart, a Tablix and a sub-report I am able to display Chart & Tablix but not the Sub report, it is giving me the below error, what shall I do to display all of them in one report? Please help me why I am not getting the report, what probably missing on my side?



The error says that the sub report cannot be found. How are you referring to the subreport? Did it move? It looks like you're in the Report Designer (PBI report builder now?) where it should have the drop down to select one that exists in the Subreport object properties.

Yes I guess I am referring correctly, all those rdl files are in the same folder, when I am checking the Preview, it is throwing me this error. Is there any detail that I missed from putting in the question my friend.

Try reselecting the subreport in the drop down of the subreport object. I think it's worked in the past.

Yes I have selected the report in the dropdown and I added a new picture for it in the main question now, could you please have a look at it my friend, it is giving me the same error.

It looks like it should be working. Check Adel's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534606/error-the-subreport-could-not-be-found-at-the-specified-location-please-verify for other troubleshooting.

@HannoverFist yes it worked for me my friend, thank you so much. just deleting the rdl.data files started showing the report & sub reports. Thank you so much again.
